# How to write a directive in Angular.js to scrape dom for data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm an Angular.js noob and need help with a tiny issue. The CMS I work in does not have a service & will not output JSON. My only option is to get my data from the dom. I know this is not ideal and in a perfect world things would be different but they are not.

I have a div on the page hidden with CSS with the class of .people-data inside of that is an unordered list. This is my service :)

I believe I need to maybe wrap my jQuery that is scraping the dom for data in a 'directive' but don't know how to do it. It feels wrong to have this jQuery sitting in the controller.

Maybe I don't even need jQuery to get this data.. can Angular do stuff like this?

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

angularApp.controller('PeopleCtrl', ['$scope', function PeopleCtrl($scope) {

$scope.people = [];

    // don't want this in controller.. scraping dom for data
    // a directive?? how and where does it go?
    $('.people-data li').each(function(){
      $scope.people.push({ 
          name: $(this).find('.name').text(), 
          email: $(this).find('.email').text() 
      });
    });

} ]);
```

Here is the Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/kUqL9f?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I made a new Plunk with a directive here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9FLIyWSzfm77SbvyBys?p=info

Basically, you need to add:

```
angularApp.directive('domScraper', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.people = [];
      $('.people-data li').each(function() {
        scope.people.push({
          name: $(this).find('.name').text(),
          email: $(this).find('.email').text()
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And then, you just need to add the attribute **dom-scraper** to the element on which you set your controller on.

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl" dom-scraper>
```

I added a console.log in your controller to show you that the directive and the controller share the same scope, since I don't know what you want to do with the data.

In your index.html, I also switched jquery and angular. Angular uses a light version of jQuery, unless you are requiring a jQuery library **before** the angular library. Since you are requiring jQuery it is better to put it before.
You can about it there:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/6A3Skwm59Z4

Hope it helps.